# Maven Embedded 3.3.9 - Is it possible?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-embedder

So I am trying to embed maven in my code rather than use a shell wrapper however I am having issues getting it to actually work.

[Source Code](https://github.com/tc-turner/maven-embedder-otg/tree/339)

The `master` branch works however it is an older version of maven (3.1.1) and I would like to use a more recent version.

The `339` branch has every dependency that I can pin down for that version defined in pom.xml.

However no amount of playing with the dependencies will help avoid the following error.

```
java -jar maven-embedder-example-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar package
[main] WARN Sisu - Error injecting: org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.classrealm.ClassRealmManager was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:585)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:243)
    at tc_turner.maven_embedder_example.Main.main(Main.java:10)
[main] WARN Sisu - Error injecting: org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors: ....... More of the same
```

I have gone through every SO question I can find and read lots of mailing lists but it seems like very few people want to do this or I am just failing.

Do you fine folks have any idea?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I am running this inside of an in house automation system and want to avoid using a process wrapper.

Comment: What is the problem? Why not simply calling maven as usual from command line which works ...The question is what kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Because the environments this will run in do not have a maven installation. If I can get this to work then it solves a lot of issues with distribution.

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 3):

I've just hit the same problem as you. I hope it's not too late for a solution.

The problem you got is related to use maven-embedder inside a shade/fatjat/jarwithdependencies

When you create the jar-with-dependencies, some resources may be defined in many jars but only one is packed inside the jar (the last one processed). Here is where the problem lays with the `META-INF/plexus/components.xml` and `META-INF/sisu/javax.inject.Named` files required by Maven and Plexus

The fix this problem you should:

- Exclude all this files when building the jar-with-dependencies
- Create this files in your project as the concatenations of the files contained in you dependencies.

In my case, I use maven-shade-plugin to build the jar-with-dependecies. So to exclude the files from the dependency jars is done this way:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Starter</Main-Class>
                                    <Main-Verticle>main.Main</Main-Verticle>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.sonatype.plexus:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/plexus/components.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/sisu/javax.inject.Named</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.apache.maven:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/plexus/components.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/sisu/javax.inject.Named</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.eclipse.aether:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/sisu/javax.inject.Named</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>io.vertx:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/sisu/javax.inject.Named</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.eclipse.xpand:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.mod4j.org.eclipse.xtend.util:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.ibm.icu:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.mod4j.*:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>*:*:tests</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                                <shadedClassifierName>fat</shadedClassifierName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This way only the `META-INF/plexus/components.xml` and `META-INF/sisu/javax.inject.Named` created in your project are included in the fatjar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  However I was using Spring Boot, so was able to use the repackage goal of the spring-boot-maven-plugin to build my fat jar, rather than the maven-assembly-plugin or the maven-shade-plugin.

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>    
          <mainClass>com.acme.test.Application</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```